# Angular drag & drop: How to prevent an item from being dropped in an unwanted list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm trying to use [the drag and drop feature provided by angular material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) to be able to move items from the **Options** list to either the **Incude** or **Exclude** list(whatever is enabled depending on the selected radio button in the **Where to move** group)

[image]

So far it works, but there's something weird when only the `Include` list is enabled.

If I try to move an item to the **Exclude** list, instead of item the being returned to the **Options** list, it is added to the **Include** list. It only works as expected if I drag the item without hovering over the Include list.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent the item from being dropped inside the **Include** list when what I wanted to do was to drop it inside another list?

BTW, this has nothing to do with the **Exclude** list being disabled. I already tested this having both lists enabled and always wins the first list I passed on my way to dropping the item in the desired list.

[Here's a demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-3-lists)

Answer (score 0):

The drag and drop library saves the last active container and adds the draggable item to it when it's dropped. Which means if you drag an item over the **Include** list before you drop it on the invalid **Exclude** list, the last active container is still the **Include** list.

It's possible to use `event.isPointerOverContainer` in your drop method to check if it's dropped outside a dropcontainer. The disadvantage of this is the animation still returns the item back to the **Include** list first..

Comment: So there's actually no possible solution ?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. You could have a look at the CdkDragRelease event. It's fired before the animation so maybe you can change the drop container in there..